# How to load js function after page load in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Im trying to load my script tag or some jquery function after page is completely loaded in vaadin. Im using javascript annotation to load my external js. like this
@JavaScript("vaadin://themes/custom/resources/js/custom.js");

Is there any way out for this to call some js function after page load or dom object created in html.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Try this approach:

```
import com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript;
...     
StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
script
    .append("var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];")
    .append("var script = document.createElement('script');")
    //...do other stuff to set up the "script" tag (add content, source, whatever)
    .append("head.appendChild(script);");
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(script.toString());
```

If you do this before the page is fully loaded, then all is good. But if you want to do this after the fact (through some event or click listener), you'll also have to use Vaadin push to push this to the JavaScript to the client. Like so:

```
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
...
UI.getCurrent().access(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //code from above that leads to JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(...)
        UI.getCurrent().push();
    }
});
```

And of course, this assumes that you have push enabled in your Vaadin application. Reference https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html

Comment: Adeel Mufti thanx alot for your help. If you don't can i have your email address please.

Comment: @hermanshafiq Hi, if this answer has fixed (or helped fixing) your issue, please consider selecting it as the correct answer to your question by clicking on the check symbol (the v) in front of the vote counter. This is the SO way of saying thanks to someone, and in doing so you'll also help other users which may have a similar issue to quickly find an answer to their problem as well. You can also add and select your own answer if you have chosen to solve it differently than any of the proposed solutions.Cheers

Answer (score -2):

As per [the docs](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), add the following in your `custom.js`

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    //call your function
});
```

Comment: This will not work as expected when using framework like Vaadin as this is a Single Page Application.

Comment: @steve Thanks for your input. Can you provide more details or samples to sustain your affirmation and explaining why this may happen? I'm asking because I've used it without any problems...

Comment: It depends on what you are using it for, as 'ready' is fired when the DOM is fully loaded. This however does not mean that the Vaadin components, html, elements are loaded and rendered. Because the poster said "completely loaded in vaadin", $(document).ready would not work as expected.